# How does Python get the log log of exE software output

Tags: python

The exe file is also written in Python, which USES Pyinstaller to convert to exe. This EXE outputs warninglevel logs at the end. For example, Logger.warning (" Hello World ") outputs "Hello World". So how do I get this "Hello World" when the main thread calls this exe subroutine?

This is the code for logTest.exe

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.warning("Something maybe fail.")
```

This is the code for output.py

```
import os
import subprocess
import logging
main=r"D:\python\commendTest\dist\logTest.exe"
f=os.popen(main)
data=f.readlines()
f.close()
```

log:

```
Something maybe fail.
```

But I want to get "Something maybe fail." into the string

Comment: I know the answer but first you have to improve your question to make it usefull for other readers here on StackOverflow. Please read "How to ask" here on StackOverflow.
Provide a **minimal working example** (MWE) where you call the exe file from a Python script. I am sure you will get close to the solution while preparing a MWE.

Comment: So you want to write a Python script that runs an exe to read its output. Are you sure that that's the best way to solve your problem? Maybe you want to give us some more context of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Because the exe tool is already written by someone else, I can only call it and get the output of his exe file